# Accessing a field of outer class from inner class

Tags: c#, .net, inner-classes

I have an inner class to contain methods of my project; and I want to use the `Form` class event handlers to call my methods from the inner class; but I am having trouble accessing members of the outer class such as `label1`, `label2`, `label3` etc.

How do I access a field of an outer class?

I'm trying to make an association inside the constructor :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // declare inner class here
    public MachineClass machineObj = new MachineClass();

    public class MachineClass        
    {
        int fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, fruitvalue1, fruitvalue2, fruitvalue3;
        public void spinslot()
        {
            Random player = new Random();

            fruit1 = player.Next(10);//generates a number between 0 and 9
            fruit2 = player.Next(10);//generates a number between 0 and 9
            fruit3 = player.Next(10);//generates a number between 0 and 9
            fruitvalue1 = fruit1 + 1;// 
            fruitvalue2 = fruit2 + 1;// 
            fruitvalue3 = fruit3 + 1;// 
            label1.ImageIndex = fruit1;//display image in label - uses image list
            label2.ImageIndex = fruit2;//display image in label - uses image list
            label3.ImageIndex = fruit3;//display image in label - uses image list

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to make the `modifiers` as `public` ?

Comment: You have a design issue. One of the major considerations in good OO design is the idea of "single responsibility" -- each class should be responsible for doing one thing and only one thing. Is `MachineClass`'s responsible to update the UI? No. So, `MachineClass` should communicate back to the UI (`Form1`) when something needs to change, and `Form1` should be responsible for updating the view. This can be achieved in a number of different ways -- you can have the UI call methods and receive results from those methods, or your class can raise events that the UI subscribes to.

Comment: @DanielMann: that's a golden advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, off the top of my head, to do this, would be for the parent class to keep reference to the child, and vice versa. So for this class structure:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public ParentClass() 
    {
         this.child = new ChildClass(this);
    }
    public ChildClass child { get; set; }

    class ChildClass
    {
        public ParentClass Parent { get; set; }
        public ChildClass(ParentClass par)
        {
            this.Parent = parent;
        }
    }
}
```

then any time you wanted to access a field in the parent class from the subclass, you could just call .Parent.Whatever. Granted, this forces you to instantiate both at the same time, so I'm not sure if it's that great a way of accomplishing what you intend, nor whether it'll work for your purposes.

Edit: Alternately, you could use ParentClass as a factory of sorts for ChildClass, like so:

```
 class ParentClass
 {
     public ParentClass() { }

     public class ChildClass
     {
         public ParentClass Parent { get; set; }
         public ChildClass(ParentClass par)
         {
             this.Parent = par;
         }
     }

     public ChildClass GetChild()
     {
         return new ChildClass(this);
     }
 }
```

and you could instantiate an unlimited number of related ChildClasses from any given ParentClass, and calling .Parent from any ChildClass would refer to the ParentClass from which it was created.

I'd like to make a note, though, that in my experience I've found very few uses for inner classes, and I can't think of a single time where the above class designs would have benefited me. Particularly given that your example doesn't really seem like it's doing anything special, it seems like you'd be better off constructing a normal class outside the scope of your Form class and passing data to it as needed, rather than trying to create a convoluted inner class with a parent/child relation.

Comment: @chouaib Editing now - one second.

Comment: @chouaib Thanks - sorry for the delay.

Comment: @furkle - I agree this is a convoluted way to do this... but for some reason my Prof is requiring we do it this way. I have this working great with just Form1 class. It makes no sense to me and maybe that is why I am having a hard time with it...seems like it should be easier to access from a public class...Thanks for your help. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @ghowell, If this helped you out, please don't forget to check the answer as selected.

Comment: @furkle - I like your last paragraph and I agree with you - this is a bad design. The only time I have found inner classes useful is in providing a completely sealed implementation of a base class where the child class inherits from the outer parent class.

Comment: @ghowell I didn't see the accepted answer show up - maybe try again later?

Comment: Nothing is working out..... public MachineClass machineObj = new MachineClass(); let me access the inner class so I can call the methods, but My inner class can not access any of the form controls? How the do you even write a calculation and then populate a label or what not.....There has got to be a more direct solution.... Can I not reference the form class in the inner class somehow? why is it so easy to access an inner from an outer but not the other way around.....I have several methods that run calculation and then populate a label on form1.....

Comment: The form class is referenced within the child class through the Parent property. That's the idea of both designs. You didn't just copy my whole example into your Form class and rename the classes, did you?

Comment: I changed the names of both cases to match mine. Let me try it again... Lost!

Comment: @ghowell I'll try to compile it myself in a minute or two.

Comment: @ghowell This works absolutely fine as I have it set up now: http://i.imgur.com/CetnmnO.png. It prints the contents of the TextBox belonging to its parent class.

Comment: maybe this is above my head... I really have no choice how I structure this because I have to use an inner class per my prof.....would you want to look at the sln.?

Comment: @ghowell Did you look at the picture I sent you? That's the entire implementation. The child class is able to reference any public property in the parent class by using child.Parent.whatever. Your answer is already complete - please check the arrow to accept it.

Comment: @ghowell Thanks - if there's any specific error messages you get, please feel free to let me know and I'll see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you really need to do to make this work and to do so with a better OO design.

First-up, define the internal `MachineClass` like this:

```
public class MachineClass        
{
    private int fruit1, fruit2, fruit3;

    public delegate void FruitUpdate(int value);

    public event FruitUpdate FruitUpdate1;
    public event FruitUpdate FruitUpdate2;
    public event FruitUpdate FruitUpdate3;

    public void spinslot()
    {
        Random player = new Random();

        fruit1 = player.Next(10);
        fruit2 = player.Next(10);
        fruit3 = player.Next(10);

        if (this.FruitUpdate1 != null) this.FruitUpdate1(fruit1);
        if (this.FruitUpdate2 != null) this.FruitUpdate2(fruit2);
        if (this.FruitUpdate3 != null) this.FruitUpdate3(fruit3);
    }
}
```

The `FruitUpdate` delegate allows the definition of three events that can let external users of this class know when updates to the fruit values occur. When updates to the fruit values occur we check that there are handlers attached to the event and then just call the events. The `MachineClass` does not need to know that there is anything listening.

Now the `Form1` class looks a bit like this:

```
public partial class Form1
{
    public MachineClass machineObj = new MachineClass();

    public void Form1_Load()
    {
        this.machineObj.FruitUpdate1 += v => label1.ImageIndex = v;
        this.machineObj.FruitUpdate2 += v => label2.ImageIndex = v;
        this.machineObj.FruitUpdate3 += v => label3.ImageIndex = v;
    }

    public class MachineClass
    {
        /* definition from above */
    }

}
```

Here the `Form1` class creates the instance of `MachineClass` and then attaches handlers to each of the fruit update events. This allows the labels to be updated without the `MachineClass` being aware of them at all!

Comment: I think you might have a typo - did you mean for every null check in spinslot() to call FruitUpdate1?